# ionic3: resources not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this error when I execute :

> ionic cordova run android --info

info ionic:

> cli packages: (C:\Users\med\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.1
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\med\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

this is screenshoot for error:

[image]

I remove platform android and i Installing but also error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Also, you may want to try this
Try running ionic resources:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/

```
ionic resources
```